# Can't import `multivariate_normal` when using `scipy.stats`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I'm trying to generate the value of the pdf of a multivariate distribution with scipy. This is the `import` statement in my script:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
```

but it's throwing an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name multivariate_normal
```

Everything else is working normally.

Comment: What versions of scipy and Python are you using? If you `import scipy.stats` then `dir(scipy.stats)`, what does it look like?

Comment: What does `python -c "import scipy; print scipy.version.full_version"` show? Needs to be at least 0.14 -- `multivariate_normal` is a fairly recent addition.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using version 0.13.3 you can upgrade at the command line with `pip install scipy --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7. I resolved it by following the steps given [here](http://tech.srij.it/2017/03/resolve-issue-cannot-import-name.html) . The problem arises because the scipy must be atleast 0.14 for stats package to work. Just doing `sudo pip install scipy --upgrade`
did not work for me. I had to upgrade the numpy and then try to upgrade the scipy, because scipy is dependent on numpy. We also need to update the build dependencies.Below are the steps I followed to fix it

Step 1) First need to make sure all scipy dependencies are installed properly

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

Step 2) Make sure the numpy, which scipy is dependent on is up-to-date

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Step 3) Make sure all the build dependencies of scipy is available

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy
```

Step 4) Rerun the upgrade

```
sudo pip install scipy --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix [not recommended]**

I upgraded numpy first, and then scipy. After that, I was able to import multivariate_normal from scipy.stats

`pip install numpy --upgrade --user`

`pip install scipy --upgrade --user`